# Can't figure out why "\n" is not removed

Tags: php, jquery

The solution is probably an easy one, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

I submit a from using jQuery's Form plug-in, then run the it through:

`str_replace(array("\r", "\n\t"), "", $_POST['mytext'])`

Looking at the HTTP header, "\n" are not added anywhere. However, when I then print $_POST['mytext'] from PHP (just for testing purposes), Firebug shows "\n" all over the place:

```
&lt;html&gt;\n  &lt;head&gt;\n      &lt;title&gt;&lt;/title&gt;\n   &lt;/head&gt;\n &lt;body&gt;\n      &lt;h3&gt;\n            We are.....
```

What's interesting is that if I select this output, manually assign it to a var and then run str_replace on it, all \n characters disappear. WHY wouldn't it do with the $_POST variable?

Please help. Going crazy with what seems to be a trivial task.

P.S. I do have a .htaccess rewrite rule, but doubt it messes with anything:

```
RewriteRule ^/update_text/? my.php?action=update_text [QSA]
```

QSA is needed to transmit other $_GET data from my JS.

---

Problem "kind of solved". I replaced $_POST with $_REQUEST and it's all dandy now. Still don't understand why $_POST would behave this way.

Comment: I don't get the problem. In PHP, you replace \r with \n and a tab character (\t). Then in the outputted text, you see \n followed by a tab character. Isn't this exactly what you asked the code to do? If you don't see \n in the header (I'm assuming that by this you mean the data sent to the server) maybe you only have \r characters in the sent data, and no \n?

Comment: Oh wait, I misread the code...

Comment: remember - \n means nothing to HTML. To display properly in a page you'd want `<br />` instead.

Comment: @Marc, I know that. I just want to remove ALL newline characters but it doesn't work in this particular case for some reason.

Comment: can we see the jQuery side of your code please

Comment: $(form).ajaxSubmit ( { data: { text_id: text_id }, 
success: function(responseText, statusText)

Answer (score 2):

your not replacing "\n" and you might be running into a the "\r\n" problem

```
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
    str_replace($order, "", $str);
```

Comment: @MarkL also what happens when you echo the results of the str_replace are there rnew lines it l

Comment: Yea, my only suggestion is assign the `str_replace` data to a value or `echo` it. Not really clear in the code example above.

Comment: tried this but still no go. 'echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), "", $_POST['text'])' shows the \n. even if I insert this into MySQL, the newline character shows up there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the PHP end of line constant? PHP_EOL

Comment: Yup, no go. Also tried preg_replace ("%\n%") but with no luck.

Answer (score -1):

I think php automatically escapes posted data - so to get it un-escaped use stripslashes($_POST['mytext']). This behavior can be changed in the php.ini settings for magic quotes, but it is a good idea to keep it there as a safety precaution against injection attacks.

Comment: `magic_quotes` is poor security to protect against [sql] injection. Which is why it is depreciated as of 5.3.0 (http://php.net/magic_quotes). The reason, is because different items need to be escaped in different ways. All `magic_quotes` did was escape them `addslashes` afaik, which does not cover all the different exploits for all the different databases etc.  -1 for bad information on security (sorry) and suggesting using a depreciated setting. It is much better to turn off `magic_quotes` and handle the escaping with the proper tools provided by the database or need of the application.

Comment: I tried that but as a result I end up with lots of "n" characters.